# Check in Data Trigger if object is particular class

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger

Is there a way to check in `DataTrigger` if the object is of a particular class?

In fact I would like that `DataTrigger` answer this question in `C#`:

```
if(MyObject is MyClass)
```

I want it to look something like this in XAML:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.Triggers>
     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyObject}" Value="MyClass?">
        <Setter..../>
     </DataTrigger>
   </Grid.Triggers>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please explain why you vote down?

Comment: @Default I do not know what to try, I ask is there a way to do it, because in search I did not find anything.

Comment: How about [x:type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753322.aspx)

Comment: @Default How can I use it on my binding?

Comment: You can try making a property that holds your type. Property will return MyObject.GetType() and Value will look like {x:Type MyObjectType}. I didn't test it, but try something in that direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a converter for this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyString, Converter={StaticResource OConv}, ConverterParameter=System.String}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
</Grid>
```

Use the ConverterParameter to state the type of the object you expect to receive...
Converter will return true if it matches or false otherwise...

Example of converter:

```
public clas s ObjectTypeToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.GetType().ToString() == (string)parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```